# What does "XP and Loot effects work through Level 10" mean?

Tags: meaning

What does "XP and Loot effects work through Level 10" mean?

In the video game, *Borderlands 3*, there is a shield, called a "Deluxe Badass Combustor", which boosts experience gain and and item drop rarity.

In its description, it says:

> XP and Loot effects work through Level 10

People online have said that the shield's effects do not work when the wearer's level, goes past 10.

But, is that what the description means? I've never heard of "X goes through Y", like "a car going through a tunnel", but the object in motion stops, inside the location it's going through.

Comment: They work up to and including level 10.  Presumably they stop working at level 11.

Comment: You’re looking at it wrong. it’s you (or your character) who are moving through levels and you do not stop. You continue to progress. It’s the effects that stop working as you progress past level 10.

Answer (score 4):

In American English (but not British English). The interval 1-10 can be described as *one through ten*. This means that one and ten are included in the range. In BE we have to use the phrase *one to ten inclusive*.

1 through 10 means every level from one, up to and including ten.

So, when you are working your way *through* level 10, XP and Loot effects work.

Comment: British English speakers would understand "one through ten" though, wouldn't they? In Australia we tend more to British English than to US, but we only need to say "inclusive" when saying "*between* one and ten" and wanting to include one and ten.

Answer (score 2):

Since you progress through levels, from level one through level two, three and all the way to level eleven and beyond, it means that it will work for the entire time you are progressing through level ten, until you reach level eleven.

Taking your example of a car going through a tunnel, imagine that the start of the tunnel is level one and the tunnel ends right at the division between level ten and level eleven.